# Sitecore: How do I retrieve the 'Display Name' in XSLT

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I've tried
`<sc:text field="Display Name" />`
and
`<xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Display Name',.)"/>`
and
`<xsl:value-of select="sc:field('Display Name',.)"/>`
with various different case and spacing.

All I can find online are examples of how to retrieve it in .NET code   `Sitecore.Context.Item.DisplayName`

Am I missing something obvious? This has been bothering me for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most standard fields on a Sitecore Item are prefixed with double underscores. I believe you'll find your value on "__display name".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method displayname from the XSLHelper (namespace:Sitecore.Xml.Xsl)
this would be used in xslt like this

```xsl
<xsl:value-of select="sc:displayname($sc_currentitem)" />
```

note : you don't have to check if there is a displayname to get 
 the name since method already does this for you.

```cs
public string DisplayName
{
        get
    {
        if (!UserOptions.View.UseDisplayName)
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
        string text = base[FieldIDs.DisplayName];
        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```